# How to make region transient in elisp when in transient-mark-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote an elisp macro that preserves the region when in `transient-mark-mode`:

```
(defmacro keep-region (command)
  "Wrap command in code that saves and restores the region"
  (letrec ((command-name (symbol-name command))
           (advice-name (concat command-name "-keep-region")))
    `(progn
       (defadvice ,command (around ,(intern advice-name))
         (let (deactivate-mark)
           (save-excursion
             ad-do-it)))
       (ad-activate (quote ,command)))))

(keep-region replace-string)
(keep-region replace-regexp)
```

This preserves the region for commands that are advised using the `keep-region` macro; very helpful when you want to make multiple replacements in a selected block.

The problem is that after running a command that has been advised using this macro, the region loses its transient nature; subsequent movement commands extend the region, rather than deselecting it.

How can I programmatically re-enable the transience of the marked region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that after running a command that has been advised using this macro, the region loses its transient nature; subsequent movement commands extend the region, rather than deselecting it.

You should rather talk about "shift-selected nature": movement commands extending the region is what happens when the mark is activated in the "normal" way.

The shift-select status is stored inside the `transient-mark-mode` variable, and is modified by someone (`handle-shift-selection`?) who doesn't care about the value of `deactivate-mark`. We can get around this by saving the value of `transient-mark-mode`:

```
(defmacro keep-region (command)
  "Wrap command in code that saves and restores the region"
  (letrec ((command-name (symbol-name command))
           (advice-name (concat command-name "-keep-region")))
    `(progn
       (defadvice ,command (around ,(intern advice-name))
         (let ((deactivate-mark nil)
               (transient-mark-mode transient-mark-mode))
           (save-excursion
             ad-do-it)))
       (ad-activate (quote ,command)))))
```

---

> transient-mark-mode is a variable defined in `buffer.c'.
>
> ...
>
> Lisp programs may give this variable certain special values:
>
> ...
>
> - A value of `(only . OLDVAL)` enables Transient Mark mode   temporarily.  After any subsequent point motion command that is   not
>     shift-translated, or any other action that would normally   deactivate
>     the mark (e.g. buffer modification), the value of
>     `transient-mark-mode' is set to OLDVAL.

Comment: This looks like it does the trick! Nice. `transient-mark-mode` looks like it's key.

Answer (score 2):

From `C-h f transient-mark-mode`:

> Transient Mark mode is a global minor mode.  When enabled, the
>   region is highlighted **whenever the mark is active**.  The mark is
>   "deactivated" by changing the buffer, and after certain other
>   operations that set the mark but whose main purpose is something
>   else--for example, incremental search, <, and >.

Hence, `activate-mark` after `exchange-point-and-mark` should restore the transient nature of the mark.

I am not sure, though, why you are using `exchange-point-and-mark` here, and why you are calling it twice.  In my opinion, just saving `(point)` and `(mark)` in a `let`-binding and restoring them after `ad-do-it` would be easier.  `push-mark` and `pop-mark` might help as well, since the latter automatically reactivates the mark anyway.

Comment: I'm calling it twice because the corresponding keystrokes were the easiest way I could find, in the editor, to re-select after a block action like a replacement. And `activate-mark` doesn't do the job, it's still non-transient, whether or not I call `exchange-point-and-mark`.

Comment: AIUI, `save-excursion` saves and restores point and mark; not sure why doing it explicitly would help. Also, not sure how to set the point directly, especially in cases where the length of the selected text has changed from a replacement.

Comment: FWIW, I added 500 bounty on the question in case you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your calls to `exchange-point-and-mark`.  The preservation is done by the `deactive-mark` let-binding anyway.

Comment: You're right that the preservation is not dependent on `exchange-point-and-mark`, but post-removal it still has the same problem; the selected region is still non-transient.

Comment: It is transient.  Just not the same kind of transient.  You want "transient that disappear when I make a non-shifted movement" but `C-x C-x` only gives you the "transient that disappears at the next command that comsunes or deactivates the mark".

Comment: Yes, I want the transient that transient-mark-mode gives you. That's the entire point of my question :) How do I create a selection like that in elisp for this macro?

Comment: `keep-region`, the one I wrote, the one that's in my question.

Comment: I've added 500 bounty on this question, if that improves the probability that it gets answered.

Comment: I recommend you clarify your question first, by removing all the `C-x C-x` and the `exchange-point-and-mark` which just confuse the issue.